# Is it possible to write directly from file to the socket?

Tags: c, file, sockets, buffer

I'm interested in the basic principles of Web-servers, like Apache or Nginx, so now I'm developing my own server.

When my server gets a request, it's searching for a file (e.g `index.html`), if it exists - read all the content to the buffer (`content`) and write it to the socket after. Here's a simplified code:

```
int return_file(char* content, char* fullPath) {
    file = open(fullPath, O_RDONLY);
    if (file > 0) { // File was found, OK
      while ((nread = read(file, content, 2048)) > 0) {}
      close(file);
      return 200;
    }
}
```

The question is pretty simple: is it possible to avoid using buffer and write file content directly to the socket?

Thanks for any tips :)

Comment: I've never used it so I don't want to write an answer, but take a look at [`splice`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/splice). The idea here is to do a zero-copy transfer, which will at least save you the time of copying the file data up to user space, then back down to kernel space before it gets to the socket. You can google more about zero-copy concepts, and there is an informative email exchange from Linus out there somewhere talking about `splice`. I'm talking Linux here, not sure what Microsoft's or others' equivalent is.

Comment: @yano  `splice` is very cool and general but in the specific case of sending a file to a socket, `sendfile` is easier and slightly more efficient, I believe.

Comment: @rici ah yes, I agree,, easier certainly. My guess is `sendFile` uses `splice` under the hood (for Linux anyway), but I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standardized system call which can write directly from a file to a socket.

However, some operating systems do provide such a call. For example, both FreeBSD and Linux implement a system call called `sendfile`, but the precise details differ between the two systems. (In both cases, you need the underlying file descriptor for the file, not the `FILE*` pointer, although on both these platforms you can use `fileno()` to extract the fd from the `FILE*`.)

For more information:

- [FreeBSD `sendfile()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sendfile&sektion=2)
- [Linux `sendfile()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html)

Comment: "Non-portable" - `fileno` exists in POSIX.1-2001!

Comment: @Antti it's portable between posix implementations, certainly. But it is not portable to a non-posix implementation.

Comment: but then, neither are sockets :) OP is almost certainly using a POSIX platform to write that code.

Comment: @antti: Ok, happy? Next time someone calls me out for strdup, I'll send them your way.

Comment: :D well, if there is an evidence of POSIX, then `strdup` is more than OK.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is write the "*chunk*" you read immediately to the client.

In order to write the content, you MUST read it, so you can't avoid that, but you can use a smaller buffer, and write the contents as you read them eliminating the need to read the whole file into memory.

For instance, you could

```
unsigned char byte;
// FIXME: store the return value to allow
//        choosing the right action on error.
//
//        Note that `0' is not really an error.
while (read(file, &byte, 1) > 0) {
    if (write(client, &byte, 1) <= 0) {
        // Handle error.
    }
}
```

but then, `unsigned char byte;` could be `unsigned char byte[A_REASONABLE_BUFFER_SIZE];` which would be better, and you don't need to store ALL the content in memory.
    }

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. There must be an intermediate storage that you use for reading/writing the data.

There is one edge case: when you use memory mapped files, the mapped file's region can be used for writing into socket. But internally, the system would anyway perform a read into memory buffer operation.